# Reference (\ref) doesn't appear

Tags: cross-referencing

I have this very basic document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\label{a}
Reference \ref{a}
\end{document}
```

However after compiling it several times, the document I obtain only has "Reference" and not "Reference 1". What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are referencing nothing, since there is no counter increased with `\refstepcounter` for that small document. `\label` needs `\refstepcounter`, since that macro defines `\@currentlabel`, which holds the counter value (or better: reference format) (Of course, `\@currentlabel` can be defined beforehand in order to create 'fake' labels)

Now, `latex.ltx` defines an empty `\@currentlabel` before `\begin{document}` and that information is used by `\label`, so you're seeing `Reference` and not `Reference 1`.

The `.aux` file of that tiny OP document is tiny too:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{a}{{}{1}}
```

There is the label name `a` and the cross-reference information after the name, i.e. `{{}{1}}`. The first brace-pair inside there is empty here whereas the second one has `1` as content, this is the page number, but not the reference number as requested -- `LaTeX` wrote an empty `\@currentlabel` content to the `.aux` file.

Here is the relevant code from `latex.ltx` (lines 4089f), comments by me.

```
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}% Use `\@currentlabel`
  \@esphack}
\def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}% Define `\@currentlabel`
}
\def\@currentlabel{}% Empty definition at the beginning.
```

Assuming a standard document class like `article`, for example `\section` (not `\section*`) uses `\refstepcounter{section}` internally (actually it is `\@sect` that calls that macro, but let us ignore this for a moment, also the fact that `secnumdepth` must have the appropiate value) and following example will provide a reference:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}\label{a}
Reference \ref{a}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism depends on the `\label` instruction being associated with some `counter` variable -- this could be a counter associated with a `figure` or `table` environment, as well as with `\section`, `\subsection` etc headers -- being incremented. (The incrementing generally takes place "behind the scenes" and isn't visible to the casual writer.)

If, for some reason, you do NOT want to create a cross-reference of the `\label`-`\ref` variety, you should look into loading the `hyperref` package and using its `\hypertarget`-`\hyperlink` cross-referencing mechanism.

Both the `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` macros take 2 arguments -- not 1 as is the case with `\label` and `\ref`. Consider the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=black]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hypertarget{item:a}{a}
\clearpage
Reference \hyperlink{item:a}{item a}
\end{document}
```

Observe that the first arguments of the `\hypertarget` and associated `\hyperlink` instructions are (in fact, must be!) the same.

Upon compilation, one gets a two-page document. In the compiled document, if you click on the string "item a" in the second page, the viewer should take you to the "a" string on the first page. (Observe that the hyperlink is, by construction of the example, not directly visible since the link color was set to black in the document's preamble.)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was using section*{} instead of section{}.
Secondly, I had to put the \label tag below the \caption tag.
After changing these, the problem was resolved.